# jQuery Menu, Prevent constant loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have made a jQuery menu, Looks great, works a treat. The only problem I have is when a user mouse's over it, It tends to "Bounce" quite a bit on a few mouseOver and mouseOuts, becoming slightly annoying and to a point where we may have to scrap it.

Does anyone know a way to stop it, or certainly slow it down.

An example is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/rtcjr/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop animation use jquery [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

And maybe http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html plugin helps you:

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's
>   intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It works like
>   (and was derived from) jQuery's built-in hover. However, instead of
>   immediately calling the onMouseOver function, it waits until the
>   user's mouse slows down enough before making the call.

Comment: That hoverintent seems pretty impressive, will give it a check.